# Numpy array as element of pandas dataframe management

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, multiple-columns

I'm considering a Pandas Dataframe. I would like to find an efficient way in which the second Dataframe is created every time the name of a column contains the number 4 and therefore column elements are arrays.

```py
 import pandas as pd
 data = {"A4aa":[[1, 2,3,4]], "B":[12,],"B4bb":[[5, 6,7,8]]} 
 data1 = {"A0aa":[1],"A1aa":[2],"A2aa":[3],"A3aa":[4], "B":[12,],"B0bb":[5],"B1bb":[6],"B2bb":[7],"B3bb":[8]}  
 df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

```py
        A4aa         B        B4bb
0   [1, 2, 3, 4]    12  [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

```py
data1 = {"A0":[1],"A1":[2],"A2":[3],"A3":[4], "B":[12,],"B0":[5],"B1":[6],"B2":[7],"B3":[8]} 
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

```py
   A0aa A1aa  A2aa  A3aa   B  B0bb  B1bb  B2bb   B3bb
0   1     2   3      4    12   5    6      7     8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def f(df):
    def g(c):
        pre, *suf = c.split('4')
        if suf:
            return pd.DataFrame(df[c].tolist()).add_prefix(pre).add_suffix(''.join(suf))
        else:
            return df[c]
    return pd.concat(map(g, df), axis=1)        

f(df)

   A0aa  A1aa  A2aa  A3aa   B  B0bb  B1bb  B2bb  B3bb
0     1     2     3     4  12     5     6     7     8
```

Comment: Sorry I simplified the problem too much and the solutions are not overlapping, I'm trying to adapt it. If by chance I could post an efficient solution with this new complication it would be perfect

Comment: @StefanoBarone try that

Comment: Thank you very much a little more elegant but more or less the same solution that I was able to get from your first answer.